Firebase Signin failing after re-install the ssl certificate
Project Tooling
Front-end app built with NuxtJS 3, Back end app built with express js. Both apps are running in docker containers, and have an extra container for certbot. I am using Lets encrypt's certificate.
Detailed Problem Description
My app is integrated with the firebase authentication service and have features for Google and Microsoft logins. Recently i have re-installed my app (re-installed ssl certificates too) in server as part of a new a release, after the release the sign in with google and microsoft functionalities are not working. I am using signInWithPopup method and i have tried to replace it with signInWithRedirect function but the call back function getRedirectResult is not getting the data.
Here is the error when pop being automatically closed.
FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/popup-closed-by-user).
    at Te (1npBjZnL.js:31:754)
    at p (1npBjZnL.js:31:66)
    at 1npBjZnL.js:871:1473

Note: The sign in functionalities are working in localhost and without https in server too.
Steps and code to reproduce issue
Re-install the ssl certificate and try to login using microsoft or google.
